# Google AppEngine's dev_appserver.py failing with "invalid command name 'app.yaml'"

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

From the [AppEngine Standard Environment quick-start](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart), I called,

```
$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

which failed then returned,

```
invalid command name 'app.yaml'
```

I executed the command in the `hello_world` directory, which holds,

```
$ ls -l .
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 generativist  staff   91 Aug  9 06:43 app.yaml
-rw-r--r--  1 generativist  staff  828 Aug  9 06:43 main.py
-rw-r--r--  1 generativist  staff  791 Aug  9 06:43 main_test.py
```

Google SDK is installed (I use gcloud daily),

```
$ which dev_appserver.py
/Users/generativist/.external_repos/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't repro. Which version of the SDK?

Comment: 166.0.0 according to /google-cloud-sdk/VERSION

Answer (score 2):

Doh!

Default Python env on this computer is Anaconda 3.6. Creating a new env with python 2.7 and `source`ing it fixed the problem.

Thanks for the effort, Dan.